# Graphic in M15, indicators in H4

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to display a chart in M15 timescale and having an indicator below showing the current value of the MACD and RSI in H4. Numbers shall be repeated 16 times and change only every 16 candles of my M15 chart, but that would help me see the progress of teh H4 indicator without changing graph.
I am currently trying with "security" function but realises that functions like MACD or RSI on the sources provided in 240 does not return proper result.
Has anyone tried this already ?
Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the higher TF results returned by your `security()`call don't look OK, it's most probably because of how you use it. This chart shows our [MTF Selection Framework - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/90mqACUV-MTF-Selection-Framework-PineCoders-FAQ/) script running RSI and showing identical values for the 4H TF from both the top 15min chart and the 4H chart at the bottom:

[image]